# How can I use an anchor tag to open a modal page?

Tags: html

I have an anchor tag in my navbar which I'd like to use to open up a modal form as a helper page. I have used the default W3Schools modal form just to test it it works. However nothing opens, I know it has something to do with the href. But i'm just not sure how to point the href to a modal form.

HTML:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="PageNavigation">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="NavigationLinks">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("DASHBOARD", "Index", "Dashboard", "", new { @class = "MainNavText", @id = "MainNavDashboard" })</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("EXPORT", "Index", "Dashboard", "", new { @class = "MainNavText", @id = "MainNavExport" })</li>
                            <li><a data-target="#myModel" data-toggle="modal" class="MainNavText" id="MainNavHelp">HELP</a></li>
                         </ul>
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </div>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Found it.

```
<li>
    <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="MainNavText" id="MainNavHelp" 
       href="#myModal">HELP</a>
</li>
```

Just needed to set the id to the `href`.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'll stick to how it is right now as some users could have javascript turned off. It's a very small chance but it's easier to use bootstrap

Comment: @AndrewKilburn Actually Bootstrap uses JS to open the modal dialog. If the user has JS turned off neither Bootstrap or jQuery will work. In fact, Bootstrap JS module rely on jQuery (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/dist/modal.js#L534)